# Finding repeating numbers within a column in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, repeat

I'm making a digital Bingo board using numbers and I want all the numbers to be unique. So I'm trying to create an algorithm that will loop through the column, find repeating numbers and then replace them with a random number between two certain numbers.

This is what I have so far:

```java
public void bingoBoardGenrerator(int[][] bingoBoard) {
    for (int row = 0; row < bingoBoard.length; row++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 15) + 1;
        bingoBoard[row][0] = random;
        for (int j = 1; j < bingoBoard.length; j++) {
            if (bingoBoard[j][0] == random) {
                bingoBoard[row][0] = (int) (Math.random() * 15) + 1;
            }
        }
```

The output should look like this but without the repeating numbers in the columns:

```
 Free space = 0

B   I   N   G   O   

5   25  36  53  61  
9   19  36  60  62  
1   17  0   54  63  
6   20  37  57  71  
5   19  39  57  69
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the "B" column:

1. Create an `ArrayList` with the Integers 1-15.
2. Then use the `Collections.sort()` to randomize the numbers.
3. Then take the first 5 numbers from the `ArrayList` and add them to your `Array`

Repeat the above steps for the I, N, G, O columns each using the appropriate range of numbers.

Or another approach (for the B) is to:

1. Create a Set.
2. Generate a random number in the range 1-15
3. Add the number to the set
4. If the set contain 5 number you are finished. If not, repeat steps 2 - 4.

Repeat the above steps for the other columns.

Comment: I'm doing this for school project and my teacher won't let us use that method. But thanks anyway!

Comment: And yet the teacher lets you copy code from a site? Isn't the point of an assignment for you to figure out the logic and implement it?

Comment: Yes but when I've spent hours trying to figure something out without success I ask people for help. None of my classmates have figured it out either so I decided to ask the internet lol.

Comment: *I want all the numbers to be unique.*  Well, I doubt the assignment is to find repeating number in a column and replace those numbers with a non repeating number. I'm guessing the assignment is to simply generate 5 unique numbers. The standard approach would be to 1) generate a number 2) see if it exists in the array and repeat until you have 5 numbers. You have been given two approaches. If they don't help then we can't guess what other restrictions you have.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the other approach. Thank you!